# IDE setup for development of react-native JSI native modules

Tags: android, c++, react-native, android-studio, clion

JSI is about to become quite popular in native module development but there's still very little information on how to get started with it.

One of the things I'm wasting more of my time on is setting up an IDE to get IntelliSense / code completion with the c++ side of things.
I have both CLion and Android studio and i couldn't figure out a way to make it work at all. Android studio seems to just ignore the CMakeLists.txt file inside the android/ folder. On clion when loading the CMakeLists.txt file it just can't find half the variables and paths needed and if i manually set the variables via the settings it keeps giving errors on errors.

I'm pretty new to c++ development but i managed to setup a few c++ projects so far, but i have no idea how to do this for RN.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you need two IDEs, one for react-native's codes, and one for C++ code.

In my experience, `Qt Creator` IDE had best support for `CMakeLists.txt` as project, but give newer MSVC versions a try (they added support recently).

Also, VS Code was good for react-native.

> But if you don't write much C++ code, simply use `VS Code` for both.